# sqlite3 - how can I get `ALL FLAGS` used in compilation?

Tags: linux, c++

In short, I'm facing something very regular ?q=Expression+tree+is+too+large+(maximum+depth+1000).

- Linux: Kali linux 2022.1 ( 5.15.0-kali3-amd64 )
- Full: Linux kali 5.15.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.15.15-2kali1 (2022-01-31) x86_64 GNU/Linux

I've tested embedded 3.37 libsqlite3.

```
# sqlite3 --version
-- Loading resources from /root/.sqliterc
3.37.2 2022-01-06 13:25:41 872ba256cbf61d9290b571c0e6d82a20c224ca3ad82971edc46b29818d5dalt1
```

And all what I can get from Debian's official ftp:

v. 3.38

```
 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sqlite3/libsqlite3-0_3.38.1-1_amd64.deb
 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sqlite3/sqlite3-tools_3.38.1-1_amd64.deb
 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sqlite3/sqlite3_3.38.1-1_amd64.deb
```

and
v. 3.34

```
 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sqlite3/libsqlite3-0_3.34.1-3_amd64.deb
 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sqlite3/sqlite3_3.34.1-3_amd64.deb
```

Apparently, bug started since 3.37. Because, I've not seen it in Kali 2021.3 - where 3.36 is situated, and 3.34 - does not affected too.

So, since 3.37 - and 3.38 - bug starts appearing.

Now, I'm trying to realize, what exactly difference of all this `libsqlite3`. I've downloaded [git repo](https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite.git). However, when I'm starting grepping by `sqlite3 --version`'s hash: `872ba256cbf61d9290b571c0e6d82a20c224ca3ad82971edc46b29818d5dalt1`

```
# git log | grep -i 872ba256cbf61d9290b571c0e6d82a20c224ca3ad82971edc46b29818d5dalt1
```

I'm getting nothing, because - this hash is from Debian's build, not from git's source log.

However, I can get Debian's source.xz archives:

```
http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sqlite3/sqlite3_3.34.1-3.debian.tar.xz
http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sqlite3/sqlite3_3.38.1-1.debian.tar.xz
```

There are Makefiles called `rules`:

```
# head 34/debian/rules 
#!/usr/bin/make -f
#-*- makefile -*-

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

export LC_ALL:=C.UTF-8

export DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS = hardening=+all
DPKG_EXPORT_BUILDFLAGS = 1
```

I can see, 38's - disable amalgamation flag:

```
# diff 38/debian/rules 34/debian/rules
7,8d6
< export DEB_BUILD_ARCH_OS ?= $(shell dpkg-architecture -qDEB_BUILD_ARCH_OS)
<
70c68
<         --enable-json \
---
>         --enable-json1 \
73d70
<         --disable-amalgamation \
92,95c89
< ifeq (,$(findstring $(DEB_BUILD_ARCH_OS),kfreebsd))
<       # build tools
<       $(MAKE) showdb showjournal showstat4 showwal sqldiff sqlite3_analyzer
< endif
---
>       $(MAKE) sqldiff
124,128c118
< ifeq (,$(findstring $(DEB_BUILD_ARCH_OS),kfreebsd))
<       install -m 0775 showdb showjournal showstat4 showwal \
<               sqldiff sqlite3_analyzer \
<               $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin/
< endif
---
>       install -m 0775 sqldiff $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin/
135c125
<       rm $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)/libsqlite3.la
---
>       rm $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/*/libsqlite3.la
```

I'm not sure is this is a right place, where bug is appearing.
And I want to see somehow confirmation to this.

**My question: How can I get from binary `/usr/bin/sqlite3` - `ALL FLAGS` which is used to compile it?**

**Up-Date:**
I'm asking about version 3.36 - which is kali2021.3. Because, the sources of this package not exists anymore. Not in Kali's nor in Debian's repos. So, the earliest one which I have - is 3.34... which is quite far than 3.36. So, there is no `Makefile` / `rules` anymore...

Comment: There is no `Makefile` / `rules` anymore!!!

Comment: If you want an history of Debian's sources to pinpoint more precisely the version (once an answer to the question tells what to check), that's available with https://snapshot.debian.org/ . So: https://snapshot.debian.org/package/sqlite3/